# Accept the number 0 at the beginning of the input

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, input

I work with symfony framework and I have an input field in a form called 'PostalCode' that is a integer type, I like that is accept the number 0 in the begin of the number because for exemple 01256 ? there are any solution to do that ? thanks for all your answers

Comment: Then it's not an integer, but a numeric *string*.

Comment: An integer is a numeric value, typically *without* representational formatting. This means that leading zero's are gone (unless you explicitly add them again when displaying your value, but they are not *stored*), as well as thousands-separators. If you want people to input leading zeroes, make it a string field.

Comment: try it yourself, e.g. with regex101.com, it shouldn't be that bad to create a regex for a postal code which accepts a `0` at the **first position**

Comment: @GolezTrol add your comment as answer

Comment: @DhiaEddineFarah you cant have an integer with leading zero's

Comment: @Neodan I would, but it's more a general remark about the misconception of integers vs formatted numeric strings. I don't know how to apply that to Symfony, so I think I can't give a complete answer. Feel free to incorporate my comment in an answer if you do.

Comment: @GolezTrol OP must use string (varchar) not integer

Comment: @GolezTrol put your solution as an answer your are right: I can change it to string value than I can add a constraints to accept only numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An integer is a numeric value, without representational formatting. This means that leading zero's are gone, as well as thousands-separators.

You may explicitly add formatting again when displaying your value, but it is not *stored* as part of the integer. For that reason, an integer input field will allow numeric input, but will typically discard such formatting information.

So, if you want people to input leading zeroes, make it a string field so they can type anything. You may provide additional rules for your input validation (for instance a regular expression that must be matched) to encourage people to type valid input instead of just some random characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex expression to check the format of your PostalCode and allow a 0 in the first position like this : #^[0-9]{5]$#

- The expression begins with a number and ends with a number : #^$#
- Number between 0 and 9 : [0-9]
- A postal code has 5 digits : {5}

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but the problem if I tried to submit 01234 for exemple -> in the database the value well saved like this: 1234 (without 0 )